# Saving data type when creating a dictionary

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to save the data type when creating a dictionary.

The following example always stores all variables as a string:

```
arr = {}
for value in self.method_list[method]:
    try:
        arr[value] = urllib.parse.unquote(request.GET[value])
    except KeyError:
    pass
```

result: `{'sign': '123'}`

I need to have the numeric data stored as int:

```
arr[value] = int(urllib.parse.unquote(request.GET[value]))
```

result: `{'sign': 123}`

How can I automatically create a dictionary with the right types?

Comment: You are already doing it in `arr[value] = int(urllib.parse.unquote(request.GET[value]))`, what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that different data arrays are gen- erated in this dictionary, both strings and numbers, I can not guess in advance the type of data

Comment: @Dmitry Then handle it accordingly. You can run a condition to check whether you have *digits* or *alpha* and perform your casting after the check.

Comment: Well, don't do this then. Use a form, or use django-rest-framework and create a serializer.

Comment: ^^ and yeah that would work even better

Comment: I do not need an extra dependency django-rest-framework, i just want to get all the data and validate them with the next step

Comment: @Dmitry Whichever method you want to go with, the comments here provide you with different options. You should be able to figure something out from here.

Comment: You can use regex patterns to do it, checking if your value has letters, points, and then treat that.

Comment: Django request.GET stores everything in rows?

Comment: Only checking between int and str solve your problem? Something like this: data = urllib.parse.unquote(request.GET[value]); arr[value] = data if data.isalpha() else int(data)

Comment: @Fabiano Yes it solves my problem, just this situation is a bit unexpected, I thought that types should be kept

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = {}
for value in self.method_list[method]:
    try:

        arr[value] = {"value": urllib.parse.unquote(request.GET[value]),
                      "type": type(urllib.parse.unquote(request.GET[value]))

    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
if urllib.parse.unquote(request.GET[value]).isdigit():
    arr[value] = int(urllib.parse.unquote(request.GET[value]))
else:
    arr[value] = urllib.parse.unquote(request.GET[value])
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will translate numerical values to Python `int` objects:

```
from __future__ import print_function

keys = [ 'key1', 'key2', 'key3' ]
vals = [ 123, '456', 'number' ]

arr = dict()

for i in range(len(keys)):
    try:
        arr[keys[i]] = int(vals[i])
    except ValueError:
        arr[keys[i]] = vals[i]

print(arr)
```

which gives:

```
{'key3': 'number', 'key2': 456, 'key1': 123}
```